# Which Ubuntu Flavour Should I Choose for Web Development?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, ubuntu-mate

I have some question:-

**01. Which Ubuntu version should I choose for Web Development?**

*My Laptop Specification:-*

1. Model: HP 15-da0021tu
2. Intel Celeron N4000 (1.1 GHz base frequency up
   to 2.6 GHz)
3. 4 GB DDR4 Ram
4. 128GB SSD

**02. Can I use same software which I can use in Ubuntu? (I am a regular ubuntu user)**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Comment: You can use the same software on any Ubuntu flavor, however they may not all run it as efficiently as other choices, picking the desktop that shares the same libraries as your end-use applications will mean you're not needing multiple libraries that do the same thing (one for desktop, one for end-user application) and thus using more resources. If you've 8gb or more; you can ignore this. You didn't specify release, nor applications - so you can compare yourself (MATE is GTK3 for all supported releases; XFCE is GTK3 from 20.04 up, Lubuntu is Qt5 from 18.10 up etc.)

Comment: Should I use Ubuntu MATE 21.04?

Comment: @guiverc answered this already: "*You can use the same software on any Ubuntu flavor.*"

Comment: Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS will be good choice.

Comment: @JihadurRahman MATE will be a good choice if you're using GTK3 apps but we have no knowledge of what you're using. Out of the box LXQt is lighter so you've more RAM available for other apps; but if you're using GTK3 apps then the extra RAM available is mostly *moot*; ie. end-user apps + desktop decide what libraries/toolkits will be needed in memory; most efficient is picking a combination that reduces duplication. (my prior comment) which we cannot answer as we haven't said what you use. If you're a developer you should understand these details (Qt5 is used by android/windows apps too)

Comment: @JihadurRahman Try the popular flavors from live USBs without installing them. You may or may not feel a spark towards one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Advice: If you don't have a preference about which desktop environment to use, then stick to the defaults.

One of the reasons you selected Ubuntu was likely it's reputation for safe, sane defaults and a great user experience.